# How to hack OpenNi Framework

Tags: openni

I downloaded OpenNi's framework code source, Its ofcourse include c++ files and codes, so the question is How do I understand that code and framework? 
 How can I understand embedded logic which Works with Sensor? 
How can I develop some other middlewares myself?
 Which place that I should look first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too wide to be answered properly but I'll give you a place to start:

Take a look at OpenNI's "get started" and reference guide (http://www.openni.org/resources/)

The simplest way to get started is to compile the enclosed examples and work your way through them to understand how the communication with the sensor is set up.